# How do I add my alternate table cell code to the cursor adapter?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-listview

New to android here. Had a question about the cursor adapter. So here's my code:
In the cursor adapter class I have these methods:

```
public void bindView(final View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
stuff....
}



@Override
    public View newView(final Context context, final Cursor cursor, final ViewGroup parent) {

return stuff...

    }
```

I tried to add  a getview method based on what I came across online when looking for the same, which is as follows:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (!mDataValid) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("this should only be called when the cursor is valid");
            }
            if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("couldn't move cursor to position " + position);
            }
            View v;
            if (convertView == null) {
                v = newView(mContext, mCursor, parent);
            } else {
                v = convertView;
            }
            /*if (position % 2 == 0){
                convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.orangecellcolor);
            } else {
                convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greencellcolor);
            }*/
            bindView(v, mContext, mCursor);
            return v;
        }
```

the code block commented in between is my code for alternate cells. Everytime i uncomment it, it does not show errors or warnings, but crashes. Now,I just need to know how do i overwrite my code with getview, should i get rid of some of the methods i mentioned or am i doing somethign wrong for the cursor adapter class? Can anyone correct/fx the above code or point me in the direction how to fix the same?
Thanks!Justin

Comment: What is causing the crash? Post the stack.

Comment: 05-28 15:04:22.906: E/AndroidRuntime(27334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 15:04:22.906: E/AndroidRuntime(27334): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-28 15:04:22.906: E/AndroidRuntime(27334):  at com.tester.adapters.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:68)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (position % 2 == 0){
                convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.orangecellcolor);
            } else {
                convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greencellcolor);
            }
```

Instead of convertview, I used a view and worked fine.